# How can I measure the sound intensity outside my house?

Tags: measurements

If I wanted to measure the noise outside of my house, in decibels, let's say I want to take a reading every second for one month and record these measurements in a file: a CSV file or something of the like. How could I do this, and what equipment would I need?

Please assume I have a very limited budget. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really has nothing to do with sound design, it's a consumer/neighbour dispute issue, best addressed to your local authority, as they will likely have recommendations [& will very often only accept data from those recommendations]

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand who this forum is intended for. However, my project has nothing to do with a consumer/neighbour dispute. It regards how to measure and record sound intensity/noise data - so that it may be visualised and analysed by software.

Comment: If I want to measure how loud something is, but not actually record the sound, can such devices be bought cheaply and can they log data?

Comment: @24ma13wg it's called a decibel meter. There are some that can log measurements but you're talking about over 2.5 million samples. Not likely to find something cheap.

Comment: If we were to take the term 'measure' quite loosely, nothing's stopping you from connecting a cheap mic to an A/D converter and then an arduino to do the calculations and the logging. But that would not be a proper measurement since the mic is not a reference mic and calibrating it would be impossible without very expensive equipment.

Comment: This isn't really off-topic. If a person is trying to noise proof a room they need to measure. Noise proofing falls under the category of sound design, the design includes reducing noise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get cheap dB meters that will record sound levels to a file. I use [this one](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B00A7KJ9W8/ref=pe_386171_38075861_TE_item), which costs ~€50. Because it's cheap, the software is not good (I had to change the Windows region/language settings to English to get the software to work), but it'll do what you want. This meter has to be powered via USB for long-term measuring.